# Must I refuse to use prototypes as an implementation of the chain of inheritance if I want to lock the extension of my objects?

Tags: javascript

To avoid duplication of code and to provide inheritance in JavaScripts there is a prototype mechanism exists. In addition, in Javascript, each object has several attributes, with which you can to some extent prohibit the extension of the object (through the `Object.preventExtensions()`, `Object.seal()`, and `Object.freeze()` methods).

Both possibilities are interesting, but if to use they together then we will get not always what we really wanted... For example:

```
let point2d = {x:0,y:0},
    point3d = Object.create(point2d, {
        'z': {
            value: 0,
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });

// For example, now we want to prevent point3d extensions:
Object.preventExtensions(point3d);

console.log('point3d.z: ', point3d.z); // 0
point3d.z = 1;
console.log('point3d.z: ', point3d.z); // 1

/* But 'x' and 'y' was defined in the prototype and now cannot be changed for point3d,
 * because we prevented the addition new properties for point3d: */

console.log('point3d.x: ', point3d.x); // 0
point3d.x = 1;
console.log('point3d.x: ', point3d.x); // 0 again
```

Does this mean that if I want to lock the extension of my objects, then I should refuse to use prototypes as an implementation of the chain of inheritance?

Comment: I would tend to say the conception is wrong, a `point2d` isn't really a subset of a `point3d`, they should both have their own definitions. If that's really the implementation (and not just a simple, contrived demonstration).

Comment: I'd say you should [avoid data in prototype properties](http://2ality.com/2013/09/data-in-prototypes.html).

Comment: @le_m you are right. Thank you.